# How does Facebook scroll to middle of timeline banner without delay?

Tags: javascript, web, scroll

Facebook has two ways to display somebody's timeline: starting from the very top, showing the full banner, and semi-scrolled, so the banner is cut in half and the profile picture is very close to he floating navigation.

However, the semi-scrolled state seems very natural, there is no delay. The page does not suddenly jump when the content is loaded.

How is this feature implemented in general? Simple `window.scroll` seems not to be cutting it as it's too slow (has to wait for the content to load to actually have something to scroll) and rather hinders user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You assume in your question the initial loading of the page. That assumption is wrong, because the "page", so to speak, is already loaded.

When you are visiting one facebook page, and then navigate to someone's timeline, it's not a full page refresh in the browser, switching from one page to another. Rather, it's all done via ajax. The "previous" page is not really unloaded by the browser, and the "next" page is loaded via ajax.

As for the url changing, that's a different topic (history pushState).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not it. Try opening a new tab with someones profile url. You've got a point the page content is loaded dynamically, though. Not sure how that relates, however.

Comment: I suspec there is a fair amount of ajax going on even on a new tab. The first, non-ajax, request doesn't fetch the whole page